# Create CSR(Certificate Signing Request) using javascript at client side

Tags: x509certificate, pki, cryptoapi, digital-certificate, csr

I want to create CSR(Certificate Signing Request) using javascript at client side using any browser(IE, Firefox, Chrome etc).

I have google it and found some js belows like PKIJS and WEB API Crypto and HTML KEYGEN Tag.

https://pkijs.org/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto

But not able to find some relavant resources or example to generate CSR using javascript at client side.

It will be much appreciated if anyone can help me ..